# Can REST response body be compared to dynamic content in EndCondition pagination rule in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: rest, pagination, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to use the `EndCondition` pagination rule to compare a REST response body value to dynamic content, like a value from an earlier Lookup activity?

I have successfully created pipelines that paginate until an empty response like `[]` is returned, which is defined using the pagination rule below:

`"paginationRules": {"EndCondition:headers.Content-Length": "Const:2"}`

Is it possible to use pagination rules to paginate until the response body matches a dynamic content value? For example, I have tried many versions of this code (*which does not work*):

`"paginationRules": {"EndCondition:body.data.id": "Constant:@activity('LookupLastID').output.firstRow.LastID"}`

The primary problem I'm facing is that my REST source only lets me specify a `sort_order` query parameter, so without an end condition I will end up querying the API for all results every time which is not feasible. I'm interested in any solution that can solve this in Azure Data Factory, even if it does not involve using pagination rules.

I have tried various passes at referencing dynamic content in the `EndCondition` pagination rule but none were successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the `EndCondition` pagination rule to compare a REST response body value to dynamic content, like a value from an earlier Lookup activity?

Yes, it is possible to compare value from earlier Lookup activity in `EndCondition` pagination rule.

I tried with my sample Rest URL and to compare value from earlier Lookup activity in `EndCondition` you need to specify it as dynamic value like below:

```json
@concat('Const:',activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].page)
```

[image]

So, it will check the value of lookup output with EndCodition value and proceed pagination.

Comment: This is very creative and I've confirmed that it works! The only caveat is that I had to use a query parameter to limit the API to return 1 record per page using `per_page=1`, otherwise I got a "more than one object returned" error. Thanks for the help!